# jQuery .split() after last slash?

Tags: jquery, split

I haven't been able to find much documentation on .split(), and I have some code that changes the source of an image and also the target folder of the image on clicking two seperate buttons. One button changes the source folder, the other the actual jpeg name.

I had the script working fine, but now it's on live and it's multiple folders deep and when i click to change the folder, the default image hides / doesn't display the actual jpg after the last / until i click the other button. the jquery i have is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    siteUrl = 'http://webdev.timberwindows.com/wp-content/themes/TimberWindows/images/window-planner/';
    imgFldr = 'period-black';

    //on hovering the 21 or 24 colour options, change the colour of the image but not the folder
    $('#black').click(function(){
        $("#pic").attr("src",siteUrl+imgFldr+"/black.jpg");
    });

    //click the hardware buttons and change the folder where the images are coming from, but not the image itself (by name)
    $('#standardBlack').click(function(){
        $("#pic").attr("src",'standard-black/'+$("#pic").attr("src").split('/')[1]);
        imgFldr = 'standard-black';
    });
        $("#ironmongery li").click(function(){
        $('#ironmongery>li').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
        $("#colours li").click(function(){
        $('#colours>li').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
});
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. Can you post some part of markup?

Comment: Yep, here you go: http://pastebin.me/74fc57b4f094813151564c8ca00a558c NOTE: it's a wordpress template file.

Comment: good practice - to use local variable instead of call "#pic" several times.

Answer (score 1):

As you want just part after last slash:
check the following code:

```
var t="http://test.test.com/test/test.php";
console.log(t.replace(/^.+\/([^\/]*)$/,'$1'));
```

Comment: the documentaton for split and replace is documentation for regexp

Comment: Crikey, thanks eicto, but I don't understand regular expressions at all! (assuming that's a regular expression?)

How would I use this code using my earlier example and my codebin code?

Comment: `function lastslash(t) 
{
return t.replace(/^.+\/([^\/]*)$/,'$1');
}`

Comment: regexp are easy. be over you fears!

Answer (score 0):

$("#pic").attr("src").split('/')[1] will give you only the second element from splitted array whereas you need the all the splitted elements expect first 1. Please try this

```
    $('#standardBlack').click(function(){
        var imgSrc = $("#pic").attr("src");
        imgSrc = 'standard-black' + imgSrc.substring(imgSrc.indexOf('/'));
        $("#pic").attr("src", imgSrc);
        imgFldr = 'standard-black';
    });

    $('#standardChrome').click(function(){
        var imgSrc = $("#pic").attr("src");
        imgSrc = 'standard-chrome' + imgSrc.substring(imgSrc.indexOf('/'));
        $("#pic").attr("src", imgSrc);
        imgFldr = 'standard-chrome';
    });
```

Comment: Hi ShankarSangoli, this gives me an img source like this: <img id="pic" src="standard-chrome//webdev.timberwindows.com/wp-content/themes/TimberWindows/images/window-planner/monkey/burgundy.jpg">

Comment: Dont put "/" when you concatenate the folder with part of image source. Take a look at this [imgSrc = 'standard-black' + imgSrc.substring(imgSrc.indexOf('/'));] there is no "/" in 'standar-black'.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you, I have used your previous code example exactly, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have added code for StandardChrome also please take a look at my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks! I can't see any difference between this code, and what I now have in my script? I used your first example and copied it and edited the folder names as appropriate.

Comment: this line "imgSrc = 'standard-black' + imgSrc.substring(imgSrc.indexOf('/'));" will not give two "/". Its a simple concatenation.