# Remove everything after last backslash

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, typescript, node-modules

`var t = "\some\route\here"`

I need "\some\route" from it.

Thank you.

Comment: Look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764435/jquery-split-after-last-slash

Comment: It cannot be done with jQuery `:P`.

Comment: [MDN - `String.prototype.lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf)

Answer (score 143, accepted):

You need `lastIndexOf` and `substr`...

```
var t = "\\some\\route\\here";
t = t.substr(0, t.lastIndexOf("\\"));
alert(t);
```

Also, you need to double up `\` chars in strings as they are used for escaping special characters.

**Update**
Since this is regularly proving useful for others, here's a snippet example...

```js
// the original string
var t = "\\some\\route\\here";

// remove everything after the last backslash
var afterWith = t.substr(0, t.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1);

// remove everything after & including the last backslash
var afterWithout = t.substr(0, t.lastIndexOf("\\"));

// show the results
console.log("before            : " + t);
console.log("after (with \\)    : " + afterWith);
console.log("after (without \\) : " + afterWithout);
```

Comment: Thank YOU.How do I double. I tried this t.replace("\\","\\\\") it did't work

Comment: You only need to do it when you set a string value directly in code, like in the example above.  If you're getting it from somewhere else (the URL, for example) then don't worry about it :)

Comment: Where are you getting the string value from?

Comment: It's working,actually I am getting directory path from web service. And this code is for Back button. Thank you so much.

Comment: Cant you just use literal strings? `let example = 'just/like/this'? will save you a lot of hassle

Comment: @Martijn Personally, I find string interpolation ugly in Javascript (I use it everywhere in C# though!).  Also, I think for clarity, for the large number of people viewing questions like this, regular string concatenation is fine.  No need to over-complicate the answer by introducing something that's irrelevant to the question :)

Comment: Haha, I was thinking the same but the other way around. All these extra backslashes dont make it easier to read and the replace functions get funcky as well.

Comment: @Martijn I understand completely.  Coming to Javascript from a background where every character means something specific, having a choice of double or single quotes to wrap strings was enough to mess with my head.  Then they added string interpolation with a *different* string separator!!!  You can't please all of the people all of the time... :D

Comment: Keep in mind that this solution will return an empty string if there is no `\` in the string we are searching in. Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65099330/1494454) for a more generic solution or [ic3b3rg's regex based one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14462668/1494454).

Comment: [substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) has been deprecated. Use [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) instead.

Answer (score 15):

As stated in @Archer's answer, you need to double up on the backslashes. I suggest using regex replace to get the string you want:

```
var t = "\\some\\route\\here";
t = t.replace(/\\[^\\]+$/,"");
alert(t);
```

Comment: Thank You, still can't find how to double the backslashes

Comment: You need to do that within the string itself. In JavaScript "\" is the escape character, so "\k" (for example) is resolved as "k".

Comment: Use @ before a backslash in a string.
Example instead of using "C:\\Mypath\\MyFile"
use @"C:\MyPath\MyFile"
Just be sure to put the @ symbol before the opening quotes.
IMHO it makes code easier to read by using the @"\" instead of the "\\"

Answer (score 11):

Using JavaScript you can simply achieve this. Remove everything after last "_" occurance.

```
var newResult = t.substring(0, t.lastIndexOf("_") );
```

Comment: isuru, isn't this already well covered by the existing answers?

Comment: @KyleMit Cant you see? He updated his previous answer.

Comment: To add *even more* info, but even the version dated [Jan 22nd, 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14462451/revisions) includes `t = t.substr(0, t.lastIndexOf("\\"));` which is identical to your your answer